# Implementing atoi - Segmentation Fault when incrementing variable j

Tags: c, algorithm, int, atoi

The C program starts by storing an string input that is a number: "134" and stores each char into a char array.
Then it starts from the last char of the array "4" and then multiplies it by 10^0, then the next element multiplied by 10^1 and so on...

Ex:
sum = (4* 10^0) + (3 * 10^1) + (1 * 10^2)

I'm not allowed to use the built in pow library so I implemented one myself. The program works only when an input string is something in the ones or tens so like: 5 or 56 or 28, etc. but doesn't work for any number in the hundreds or higher.
**(I started receiving seg faults the moment I added j++)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int pow(int, int);
int i;
int result;
#define SIZE 10
char input[SIZE];
int j = 0;

int main(){
    printf("Enter a word of positive number or quit: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = strlen(input)-1; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("pow: %d\n", (input[i] - '0') * pow(10, j));
        sum = sum + ((input[i] - '0') * pow(10,j));
        printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
        j++;
        printf("j: %d\n", j);
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum); 
}

int pow(int base, int exponent){
    if(exponent == 0) return 1;
    if(exponent == 1) return base;
    result = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < exponent; i++){
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Which exact inputs are failing for you?

Comment: Instead of declaring every variable global, declare them per function where needed. `i, i, input` vars belong to `main`. `result` belongs to `pow`.

Comment: You could process the digits from the most significant end, multiplying the value so far by 10, then adding the value of the next digit... saves constructing the powers of 10.  (Multiply by 10 can also be implemented as s small number of shifts and adds, though full multiplies are faster these days.)

Comment: All the global variable can _and should_ be eliminated - it is bad practice.  And this algorithm is unnecessarily complex. `strlen()` and  `pow()` can be eliminated and in this case you don't even need the `input` buffer you could use `getchar()` to process one character at a time.  A 32bit `int` can be up to 10 decimal digits, so here `SIZE` is too small - if you have to deal with a +/- sign you'll need an additional character for that too.

Comment: @ChrisHall [Multiply by 10 can also be implemented as small number of shifts and adds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402347/implementing-atoi-segmentation-fault-when-incrementing-variable-j#comment106853442_60402347) is true, yet a good compiler will do that already in `sum = sum*10 + (input[i] - '0');` if indeed it is better.  Best to let the compiler do that optimization - or get a better compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have declared `i` as a global variable. It is then used as an iterator both in `main()` and `pow()`, which is not desired. This can be fixed by making the iterator local to the scope of the loop, as

```
for (int i = strlen(input)-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
```